# Update databinding on ListView SelectedItem

Tags: c#, listview

```
private void Update_Button(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
     string fname = tb_firstname.Text;
     var selectedEmployee = (Employee)lview.SelectedItem;

     if (fname != null)
     { 
         //update code
     }
}
```

How to update the selecteditem `fname` TextBox when I click the listview in the UI without using `{binding}` in the textbox?

**FLOW**

- the user will click on the listview
- the selected value will be display on the textbox
- the user will update/change the textbox
- when the user will click update_button the selecteditem of the listview will be updated..

Comment: In what user interface? WinForms, WPF, Silverlight or WinRT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare an event handler for the `SelectionChanged` event of your `ListView` in the `.xaml`:

```
<ListView Name="lview" ...
          SelectionChanged="lview_SelectionChanged" />
```

Add the event handler to your `.xaml.cs`:

```
private void lview_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Assuming the property is Employee.FirstName
    tb_firstname.Text = ((Employee)lview.SelectedItem).FirstName;
}
```